# Simultaneously usage and effect on electric cost

Tags: power, cost

Will using 2 watt devices simultaneously result in a higher electric bill than the same 2 if used at different times but for the same length of time (ie, 2 water fountain pumps together for 12 hours versus 1 pump for 12 hours and pump the other 12 hours of the day)?

Comment: Zero difference if you pay for each kWh used. Some utility companies have started to bill you for peak consumption as well. Check with yours.

Answer (score 1):

Energy is what we pay for.  One unit of energy is the watt-hour or kilowatt-hour.
A simple way to figure out how much energy your device uses is to multiply its power by how long it is on.
As in your example, 2 devices and 2 Watts per device on for 12 hours.
$$Energy=2*2W*12hr=48Wh$$
Now for the second example of one device on at a time for a total of 24 hours
$$Energy=2W*24hr=48Wh$$

So you would pay the same, assuming that the power company charges consistently throughout the day/night.  Ie. They are not billing by Time Of Use (TOU).

Comment: The power lost in wiring may be insignificant, but it still is proportional to current squared. So if you have a length of wire, power lost with 2 amps is 4 times larger than power lost with 1 amp. So if both devices take constant power, the power lost in the wiring is higher when two devices consume power simultaneously.

Comment: @Justme While technically true, I would argue that if you are losing appreciable power in the wiring, then the wire guage was chosen wrong, and is quite possibly a safety hazard.  In other words, when designed/chosen properly, the wire losses should not be significant.